# How to redirect to external site from directory (from url with this site)

Tags: nginx, url, redirect, nginx-config

On many my sites there is a tradition of making redirects through an internal directory. It looks so that the external link to Yandex from site.ru looks like this:

https://site.ru/out/https://ya.ru

This url will 301 redirect to https://ya.ru.

In apache i do this in .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /out/(.*)$ 1.
```

Trying to rewrite for nginx, doing that:

```
rewrite /out/(.*) $1 permanent;
```

But it redirecting to https://site.ru/ya.ru, not to https://ya.ru.

I add this config to my.conf (i created this file in /etc/nginx) and do «include /etc/nginx/my.conf;» (in server{} of course) in all conf files of my sites.

Help me please with the config, I can't figure it out.(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the problem is that `rewrite` uses a normalised URI which has folded multiple consecutive `/`s into a single `/`. It is better to use the original request which is stored in `$request_uri`.

One possible solution is to use a `map` to extract the embedded URL. For example:

```
map $request_uri $redirect {
    default 0;
    ~^/out/(?<out>.*)$ $out;
}

server {
    ...
    if ($redirect) { return 301 $redirect; }
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details, and [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.

---

You can achieve the same thing without using a `map` using:

```
if ($request_uri ~ ^/out/(.*)$) { return 301 $1; }
```

Comment: I want to do this just including my.conf file to site conf. If i dont find other solution i will try yours.